# Odoo 15 : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-15, point-of-sale

I'm using Odoo 15 and I am encountering a persistent issue when trying to access the Point of Sale menu in Odoo, and I'm hoping someone can provide guidance on resolving it.

Here's the error message I'm encountering:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
    at ControlPanelModelExtension._extractAttributes (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:45261:46)
    at http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:45117:26 (/web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/control_panel_model_extension.js:959)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/control_panel_model_extension.js:815)
    at ControlPanelModelExtension._createGroupOfFiltersFromArch (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:45074:24) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/control_panel_model_extension.js:772)
    at ControlPanelModelExtension._addFilters (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:44900:18) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/control_panel_model_extension.js:598)
    at ControlPanelModelExtension.prepareState (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:44523:22) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/control_panel/control_panel_model_extension.js:221)
    at ControlPanelModelExtension.importState (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:93594:22) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/model.js:81)
    at ActionModel.importState (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:93873:27) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/model.js:360)
    at new Model (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:93769:18) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/model.js:256)
    at new ActionModel (http://localhost:5050/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:63508:5) (/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/action_model.js:59)
```

I've attempted creating new databases, updating Odoo source code but the problem persists, and it consistently arises after installing a custom module. Importantly, this module is unrelated to the POS module, and it does not contain any JavaScript code.
Any insights into what might be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What's troubling you is an error that see­ms linked to putting the field.type­ value, since you do not have any javascript files, please inspect the xml files. Try by commenting xml files from __manifest__.py  and reinstalling the module.  Without the the full code­ or the specific situation, it's tough to pinpoint the proble­m exactly.

Comment: More details are needed here.
Do you have customizations?
Are you coming out of an upgrade?
What is the result you get when you upgrade the base module?

Answer (score 0):

If the window action your menu item calls has the view_type field defined, remove it.

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_example">
    <field name="name">Example Action</field>
    <field name="res_model">action.example</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>   <-- this is the problem
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="context">{'search_default_today': True}</field>
</record>

<!-- This is the correct version of the window action -->
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_example">
    <field name="name">Example Action</field>
    <field name="res_model">action.example</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="context">{'search_default_today': True}</field>
</record>

<menuitem
    id="example_menu_item
    name="Example"
    action="action_example"/>
```

If this does not work check any search records defined on the corresponding model. If these records are grouping by a field that is not present on the view, this ambiguous error can arise.